# MySQL : Multiple row as comma separated single row

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables : DISH and DISH_HAS_DISHES. Dish table has all the dishes and "Dish_has_dishes" table has a one-to-many relationship with "Dish" table. I.e. a dish can have multiple dishes. For example

**DISH** :

```
dish_id   dish_name
1         dish_1
2         dish_2
3         dish_3
4         dish_4
```

**DISH_HAS_DISHES** :

```
meal_id   dish_id
1         2
1         3
1         4
```

Here meal_id and dish_id both are IDs from DISH table. Now I want a format like this:

```
meal_id     dish_ids     dish_names
1           2,3,4        dish_2, dish_3, dish_4
```

That is comma separated dish id and names for each meal. How to do that?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT FUNCTION

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/grab-bag.html

```
 SELEct m.meal_Id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(dish_id) dish_ids, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(dish_name) dish_names
 FROM DISH_HAS_DISHES m JOIN DISH d ON (m.dish_id = d.dish_id)
 GROUP BY meal_Id
```

Comment: Thats awesome. Than you Micheal for your quick reply. Just one thing to ask, I am getting "dish_ids" column as "BLOB" type. Rest are proper. Why?

Comment: @Swar, Should be varchar, what is length of dish_ids? Also look to this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat. Check value of parameter group_concat_max_len, by default if resulted string will be more than 512 chars (default value) it will be returned as BLOB

Comment: They are just integers with length 11. I tested with just 4 ids - 6,7,8 & 9. Though with blob type, its working perfectly but just a query.

Comment: @Swar, very strange. in doc: The return value is a nonbinary or binary string, depending on whether the arguments are nonbinary or binary strings. The result type is TEXT or BLOB unless group_concat_max_len is less than or equal to 512, in which case the result type is VARCHAR or VARBINARY. (Prior to MySQL 5.0.19, GROUP_CONCAT() returned TEXT or BLOB group_concat_max_len greater than 512 only if the query included an ORDER BY clause.)

Comment: Somehow, blob type is coming only when the fields are INTEGERS. I tried with other fields also.

Comment: @Swar, try GROUP_CONCAT(trim(convert(dish_id, char(5)))) dish_ids, any be its help

Comment: One possible modification, GROUP_CONCAT should have DISTINCT.

SELECT m.meal_Id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dish_id) dish_ids, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dish_name) dish_names
 FROM DISH_HAS_DISHES m JOIN DISH d ON (m.dish_id = d.dish_id)
 GROUP BY meal_Id

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPakhantsov, You save lots of my time, Really appreciate it.