# How to concatenate multiple rows into a single text string without using loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Suppose i have a table with the following data:

```
ClientID    ClientName
3           saurabh Malhotra
4           patel Mon
6           Sajith raju
7           Vipin parmar
8           Monoj trivedi
```

We need to concatenate the ClientName column like the following:

saurabh Malhotra, patelMon, Sajith raju, Vipin parmar, Monoj trivedi

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: you are getting completely wrong..please read question again and then compare..

Comment: I'm not _completely_ wrong, take another look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select 
     group_concat(ClientName  separator ',') as ClientName 
from (select 1 as tempcol,
           ClientName 
     from tablename)tbl
group by tempcol
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ClientName) FROM Your_table_name
```

[MySQL : Multiple row as comma separated single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492539/mysql-multiple-row-as-comma-separated-single-row)