# How to display the data only once in php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My task is i want to display Sno,bill date,bill no partyname,item name,Qty,Amoumt,Disc %,DiscAmt and bill amount..all other columns are present in purchase bill array except itemname and i want to display itemname according to their bill no, my problem is all the columns are repeatedly printing according to the itemname...but i want to display itemname according to the items in one column and all other columns in one row..[image]
Controller code:

```
    if($this->input->post('selected'))
    {
        if($name = $this->input->post('businessType'))
        {
            $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
            $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
            $this->db->where('PName',$name);
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('purchaseitem');
            $this->db->order_by("billno", "asc");
            $this->db->join('purchasebill', 'purchasebill.no = purchaseitem.billno','left outer');
            $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
            $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
            $data['query'] = $query;
            $this->load->view('Receipt_View', $data);
         }
    }
```

View page code:

```
    <th>Bill No</th>
    <th>Bill Date</th>
    <th>Party Name</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Disc %</th>
    <th>Disc Amt</th>
    <th>Bill Amount</th>
    <!--<th>Bill Amount</th>-->
</tr>
</thead>
<br>
<tbody>
<?php $rowcount = 1 ?>                          
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$rowcount;?></td>
        <td><?=$row['no'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['date'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['PName'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Prdtname'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Qty'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['amount'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Disper'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Disamt'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Grdtot'];?></td>
  <?php $rowcount +=1 ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>

<br>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I really am confused about what actually you want, but as far as I understood, this looks similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492563/9144250

Comment: i just want to display all of the item entries according to the bill no rest of the datas will be printed once

Comment: If you want to show one row for unique bill number which will show itemnames in single column, you can use groupby query to group results per bill number  Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: but i have one problem i am not getting bill number from the user..i am just preparing a register that gets input as date..from that date i want to display the details

Comment: so date is your unique key here...use date to group your data by...your query remains the same...add one more line to groupby by date...and then in your view....change foreach as per your need...

Comment: But there is a chance of having more than one bill on the same day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182843/discussion-between-laavanya-dharani-and-exabytes-js).