# How to concatenate string values that have a similar column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mountains' Table:
[image: Mountains' Table]

I want to write a query that concatenates the countries that are in the same mountain.
So, in the result table, I'll have one a time the name of the mountain and a column which is named countries with the concatenated countries separated with commas.

Comment: Give you give an example of how the final output should look? What do you want to do with province?

Comment: Hint: `group_concat`.

Comment: Assuming you are using MYSQL a quick search on google brought back [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492539/mysql-multiple-row-as-comma-separated-single-row).  I think you want to use group_concat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Results as comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)

Comment: yes, you can use GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT (Country) as "country" 
FROM table_name group by Mountain;
```

Use GROUP_CONCAT you can learn more about it here:- [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/)